# Permutation operator on two spin 1/2 particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Suppose we have two spin 1/2 particles. Then we have a common eigenbasis $\{|m_{s1},m_{s2}\rangle\}$ to the operators $\hat S_{1z}$ and $\hat S_{2z}$. The permutation operator is defined as:

$$
\hat P_{21}|m_{s1},m_{s2}\rangle=|m_{s2},m_{s1}\rangle
$$

My job is to find the eigenvalues of $\hat P_{21}$ and its eigenkets, as well as to prove that:

$$
\hat P_{21}=\hat 1+\frac{\hat 1}{2}+2\hat{\vec{ S_1}}\cdot\hat{\vec{ S_2}}, \tag{1}
$$

Here's my attempt:

We know that for some vector $(x,y)^T$ there is a matrix that can put it like $(y,x)^T$ given by $
   M=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$, so I would expect that, after writing the (1) in $\{|m_{s1},m_{s2}\rangle\}$ basis something of the sort would come up. But after some tweeking I get that:

$$
\hat{\vec{ S_1}}\cdot\hat{\vec{ S_2}}=\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\bigg[(\sigma_x \otimes \hat 1)(\hat 1 \otimes \sigma_x)+(\sigma_y \otimes \hat 1)(\hat 1 \otimes \sigma_y)+(\sigma_z \otimes \hat 1)(\hat 1 \otimes \sigma_z) \bigg]
$$

which reduces to:

$$
\hat{\vec{ S_1}}\cdot\hat{\vec{ S_2}}=\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\bigg[(\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x)+(\sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y)+(\sigma_z \otimes  \sigma_z) \bigg]
$$

As we know that $
   \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$ , $
   \sigma_y \otimes \sigma_y=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$ and $
   \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$, we get that $ \sum_i
   \sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_1=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$. Plugging this all back in (1) we see that what we end up with is something like this:

$$
   \hat P_{21}=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
+  \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
+ \frac{\hbar^2}{2} \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$$

$$ \hat P_{21}=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   3/2+\hbar^2/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 3/2-\hbar^2/2 & 3/2+\hbar^2 & 0 \\
   0 & 3/2+\hbar^2 & 3/2-\hbar^2/2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 3/2+\hbar^2/2 \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$$

But this has no resemblance to the matrix M and tells me nothing. How can one prove (1)? Why is my approach wrong?

Comment: I think $\hbar=1$ is implicit in the eigenvalues of $\hat S_1\cdot\hat S_2$ else this operator is not dimensionally consistent with $\hat 1$.

Comment: Not really, but as it was on one of our exams I took it for granted. How should it be defined then, in a matrix representation (and operators if it exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a misprint in your question so I'll go with what I think is right.

Using the coupled basis (which is already permutation symmetric)
\begin{align}
\vert 11\rangle = \vert +\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\, ,\qquad 
\vert 10\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2
+\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)\, ,\quad \vert 1-1\rangle = \vert -\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\, ,\\
\vert 00\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2
-\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)
\end{align}
it is clear that the permutation operator will have the form
\begin{align}
P_{12}\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
&&&-1\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
with eigenvalue $+1$ on the symmetric $S=1$ states and $-1$ on the antisymmetric $S=0$ state.
The operator 
$$
\hat{\textbf{J}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{J}}=
\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_1+\hat{\textbf{S}}_2\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2+2\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2=
\frac{3}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{1}}+
2\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2
\quad\Rightarrow 2\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2=\hat{\textbf{J}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{J}}-\frac{3}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{1}}
$$
using $\hbar=1$, 
so, given that $\hat{\textbf{J}}\cdot\hat{\textbf{J}}=2$ for symmetric states and $0$ for the antisymmetric state, we see that 
\begin{align}
2\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2= 
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{3}{2}& \hbox{if } J=0\\
\frac{1}{2} &\hbox{if } J=1\, ,\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Hence, 
\begin{align}
P_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{\boldsymbol{1}}+2\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2
\end{align}

Note that in the *uncoupled basis*, with ordering $\vert+\rangle_1 \vert+\rangle_2, \vert+\rangle_1\vert-\rangle_2,\vert-\rangle_1\vert+\rangle_2,
\vert-\rangle_1\vert-\rangle_2$, we have
\begin{align}
\hat{\textbf{S}}_1\cdot\hat{\textbf{S}}_2 
=\frac{1}{4}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
and then $P_{12}$ takes the form
\begin{align}
P_{12}\mapsto\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
which clearly permutes the $\vert \pm\rangle_1\vert \mp\rangle_2$ states.  The eigenvalues and (unnormalized) eigenvectors of the $2\times 2$ submatrix are $\pm 1$ and $(1,\pm 1)^\top$, from which one can obtain the properly symmetrized combinations of $\vert \pm\rangle_1\vert \mp\rangle_2$ states.